# Cause for Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: error

Tags: 8

Currently trying to port over a Contrib module and learn the new Drupal 8 architecture.

A google search revealed a [possible issue](https://drupal.org/node/1962876) related to this.

The cause could be that there's an underscore in the file name which violates psr-0 naming standards. Looks like i had that before and have renamed it just now and still have that issue after clearing the cache.

What would likely be the cause of the following error?

> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException:
>   You have requested a non-existent service
>   "\drupal\form_example\forms\formexampleformone". in
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() (line 304 of
>   /home/chris/workspace/d8/core/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php).

The error occurs when i visit `/examples/form_example/tutorial/1`

**form_example.routing.yml**

```
form_example:
  path: 'examples/form_example'
  defaults:
    # _form: '\Drupal\form_example\Forms\FormExampleForm'
    _content: '\Drupal\form_example\Controller\FormExampleController::description'
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
form_example_tutorial_1:
  path: 'examples/form_example/tutorial/1'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\form_example\Forms\FormExampleForm'
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

**form_example.module**

```
<?php
function form_example_menu() {
//   $items = array();
//   $items['examples/form_example'] = array(
//     'title' => 'Form Example',
//     'route_name' => 'form_example',
//     'access callback' => TRUE,
//     'expanded' => TRUE,
//   );
  $items['examples/form_example/tutorial'] = array(
    'title' => 'Form Tutorial',
    // 'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'route_name' => array('form_example_tutorial'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'description' => 'A set of ten tutorials',
    // 'file' => 'form_example_tutorial.inc',
    // 'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  $items['examples/form_example/tutorial/1'] = array(
    'title' => '#1',
    // 'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'route_name' => array('form_example_tutorial_1'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'description' => 'Tutorial 1: Simplest form',
    // 'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
    // 'file' => 'form_example_tutorial.inc',
  );
  return $items;
}
```

**/lib/Drupal/form_example/Forms/FormExampleForm.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\form_example\Form\FormExampleForm
 */
namespace Drupal\form_example;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormInterface;

class FormExampleForm extends FormBase {
// form...
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your routing.yml file?

Comment: Sure thing updated @Berdir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the namespace defined in your class file does not match the one you put into the resource, there's a "Form" sub-namespace missing.

Also make sure that the class is placed in the right folder.

The reason for that error is apparently that for *some* reason, the specified class can't be found, so apparently the router then falls back to the service. So the _ thing is just one possible reason.

Also, there are some errors in your hook_menu(), route_name is a string, access callback can be removed and you still need the first entry for now so that you have a menu link to it.

Comment: I would like to add one more reference here. Definitely it is the issue with underscore. Here is the reference link for future visitors https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md#underscores-in-namespaces-and-class-names and https://drupal.org/node/1962876